# Is there a way to protect your group from friendly fire when using "Corrupted blood"?

Tags: pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous

The Lich mythic path spell "Corrupted Blood" doesn't seem as much:

> Spell Effect: You are nauseated. Additionally, if you die, you deal 6d6 damage to all creatures in 15 feet radius and apply Corrupted Blood to them.

But in practice, this spell can wipe whole armies. Why? Because the order of the events is reversed to one in the description:

1. You infect target 1 - he gets nauseated and have the Corrupted Blood
   mark. No biggie here.
2. Target 1 dies, FIRST infecting all nearby creatures with Corrupted Blood THEN dealing 6d6 damage to them
3. If any of the creatures from #2 dies from the original damage, they spread the corruption and deal the damage

Repeat step #3 until your game freezes, followed by a gory picture of absolutely everything on the screen turning into red paste. The caster included.

Is there a way to protect your party from the damage, other than running as far as you can ? I think that Lich has a spell which can turn all party members temporary into Undead (so no sickness effect), but it won't produce from the damage itself.

Answer (score 2):

The only practical way I found out is by using the Lich Power Death of Elements and having full undead in the party ( or cast Blessing of Unlife on your living pals ).

Death of Element convert all elemental damage you deal to Negative Energy, Corrupted Blood deal Unholy Damage but somehow the game identify it as elemental, as such with Death of Element it became negative energy and do not harm your party.

Side note, you take 0 damage by corrupted blood in this way, but the damage do not heal you. Do not take Ascendant Element Negative Energy if you plan to go this route, or you will wipe yourself out as you will ignore the immunity to Negative Energy.